# Es posible usar el AuthorizationAttribute de MVC como Token?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, api

hace tiempo vengo trabajando un en un proyecto con ASP MVC 5.

Ahora, se ha añadido un requerimiento, que implica la actualización de cierta información en la base de datos, además del procesado de otra, de forma rutinaria.

Por lo que pensé hacerlo de hacerlo creando una ''mini api'' y mediante las tareas programadas de Windows, realizarle la llamada de modo periódico..

Pero aquí me surgió la siguiente duda..

¿Cómo me autentico mediante una llamada a la api usando el atributo `Authorize`?

Al día de hoy, siempre he usado las extensiones de Identity 2.0, por ejemplo

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
   public JsonResult CargarTodosLosArticulos()
   {
       return null;
   }
```

y de esta manera validar que hay un usuario logueado en el sitio, además de ser admin.

Mi intención es no cambiar este método de validación.

Hoy por hoy, estoy intentando realizar la llamada de la siguiente manera

```
var request = new RestRequest(ruta);
request.AddParameter(parameterName, codigoDelfos);

var result2 = mClient.Execute<MyResponse<GetAccesoriosResponse>>(request);

if (result2.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
   throw new Exception("Fué imposible establecer la conexión con el servidor.");
}
```

¿Es posible simular este login desde una llamada como la que se ve anteriormente?

O caigo en la obligación de implementar un sistema de Token para hacerlo?

Saludos y gracias!

Comment: Lo que quieres es poder acceder a esa ruta sin enviarle las credenciales de autenticación al llamarla desde las tareas programadas pero que siempre realice la validación para los usuarios que ingresan de forma normal?

Comment: @crrlos En realidad lo que busco es poder enviarle las credenciales, pero automáticamente el `Authorize` me rechaza el request, y dando vueltas por internet no he encontrado el como enviarlas, me explico?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es crear un atributo de autorización personalizado, para eso creas una clase que extienda a `AuthorizeAttribute`  y sobreescribes el método `AuthorizeCore`. La modificación consiste en pasar a la ruta un parámetro adicional para indicarle que se está llamando desde el programador de tareas, si el parámetro no se encuentra entonces realizará la validación normal, si el parámetro se encuentra (debe tener un valor o si no será null) entonces toma las credenciales de la url y realiza la validación, si son correctas retorna un `true` permitiendo el acceso al método.

```
public class CustomAuthorization : AuthorizeAttribute
        {
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
          //obtener parámetro especial que indica que la petición se realizó desde el programador de tareas
          var parametro = httpContext.Request.QueryString.Get("parametro_especial");

          if(parametro != null)
          {
            // obtener las credenciales de acceso y validarlas
            // si las credenciales son validas return true;
          }
          //si las credenciales no son validas o el parametro_especial no está presente
          //realizar la acción por defecto
          return base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        }

      }
```

Como usarla:

```
[CustomAuthorization (Roles = "Admin")]
   public JsonResult CargarTodosLosArticulos()
   {
       return null;
   }
```

Comment: Nunca pensé llegar a una respuesta que fuera exactamente lo que buscaba, muchísimas gracias!